# Countable Borel equivalence relations and a non-measurable set.

Tags: general-topology, logic, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Given a Borel equivalence relation $E \subset [X]^2$  with countable equivalence classes (let's say generated by the action of $\mathbb{F}_2$ on $2^\omega$ via some convenient coding.) Is it necessarily the case that any selection of representatives from each equivalence class, witnesses the existence of a non-measurable subset of $X$?

(if my assumption that it's generated by an $\mathbb{F}_2$-action is too strong, feel-free to ignore it.)

Comment: In the context of countable Borel equivalences, there is a characterization: it admits a Borel transversal iff it is smooth, namely there exists a Borel reduction to $(\mathbb{R}, =)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Think about the relation $x-y\in\mathbb{Z}$ on $\mathbb{R}$; this has very simple transversals, but also has countable equivalence classes.

An $\mathbb{F}_2$-on-$2^\omega$ example, unless I misunderstand, is the equivalence relation "are equal on all but possibly the first bit." Again, this has a very simple transversal.

Comment: Thank you for the example. Also, I thought the equivalence classes generated by an $\mathbb{F}_2$-action where universal among Borel-reduction?

Comment: By $\mathbb{F}_2$, you do mean the field with $2$ elements, right? If so, the one I describe above is a pretty convincing counterexample. Maybe you want some additional hypothesis?

Comment: No, the free group with 2 generators.

Comment: @NotMike Ah (derp, of course). Well, you still need an additional hypothesis: since $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is a quotient of $\mathbb{F}_2$, any equivalence relation induced by an action of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is also induced by an action of $\mathbb{F}_2$. Maybe you mean *faithful* action?

Comment: Yes. I was assuming some background enumeration of elements of $\mathbb{F}_2=\{a_n: n \in \omega\}$ with the associated action $(g \cdot x)(n) = x(m)$ where $a_m=g\cdot a_n$ (sorry for not being explicit.)